# Where to store JWT revocation information, mongoDB or Redis?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, jwt

Currently implementing a MEAN stack user registration/login system using JWT's instead of sessions for all things auth.

In order to be able to revoke a JWT, I need to store some JWT info as part of a token blacklist. My initial thought was to use MongoDB for storing blacklisted tokens, but would Redis be suitable too? The reason I'm hesitant to avoid Redis in this case is that if the server crashes/restarts then the token blacklist would be lost, whereas with MongoDB the blacklist would remain intact / persist.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis supports multiple modes of disk based persistence.  You can enable snapshop persistence (RDB) using the `save` config directive and you can enable changelog persistence (AOF) using the `appendonly yes` config directive.

For your use case, you should probably use AOF persistence.

More information on Redis persistence can be found at https://redis.io/topics/persistence.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware Redis could persist. Will read through the manual. Out of interest, would you say there is any advantage to using Redis with AOF enabled rather than a simple Mongo solution? I would presume that data access speeds would be dependent on the size of the dataset, so Redis would be better for smaller datasets due to it existing in memory.